# XCode6 Beta 6: Is this class creation syntax no long valid in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6-beta6

I am referring the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24061386/58129

The code is reproduced here:

```
var clazz: NSObject.Type = TestObject.self
var instance : NSObject = clazz()

if let testObject = instance as? TestObject {
    println("yes!")
}
```

If I tried it in a playground in XCode6 beta6, it throws an exception:

[image]

Is it no long valid to instantiate a class by calling `T.self()`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html

Comment: Seems like an issue with playgrounds. I got the same error in a playground, but works when thrown into a non-playground project