# Swift - How to initialize object of class created with NSClassFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, class, object-initialization

**In Objective-C**

we can create class from string and initialize its object to push on navigation stack like :

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString("ClassString");
id myObject = [[myClass alloc] initWithNibName:"ClassString" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myObject animated:YES];
```

What would be the equivalent code in swift ?

**In Swift** I've tried :

```
let ClassName = NSClassFromString("ClassString")
let myObject = ClassName.init(... ) // <- here I'm unable to init with nib name
```

[image]

How can the object be initialized with class created from NSClassFromString ?

**UPDATE**

With the help of Martin's link in comment, I'm able to fix problem with Nib/XIBs. But how it can be done for stoyboard ?

```
let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let myVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeID") as ClassName // <- here I'm getting error
self.navigationController.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I tried removing 'as ClassName' from the line and its working fine.
As of now, pushing view controller using nib and storyboard is done. Now I want it to be push without both or with **frame**.

This code is just fine,but when it get pushed, it appeared as blank and black:

```
let myVC = ClassName.init()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: animate)
```

What is the solution ? If its init with frame, How can we achieve it in this case ?

*All above conditions I'm checking because I want to implement one function for push/pop operation of viewcontroller.*

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26256867/1187415 ?

Comment: Yes Martin,it does. But why it was not showing in drop down when I typed className.init ?  Thanks btw.

Comment: Because you did not cast the class to `UIViewController.Type`.

Comment: No,I did it. sorry for not posted that in question. See image in question.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing with `as ClassName`. Do you have a class literally named `ClassName`? `.instantiateViewController()` already returns a `UIViewController`, which you can already push without doing anything else

Comment: Yes, @newacct. no need to write 'as ClassName'.