# Swift, cast to type by a given string if let .. as ? someString

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, casting

I'm trying to store a dictionary `var items : [String:(type:String,item:AnyObject)] = [:]`

for example the key is "foo" and `items["foo"]?.type = "UILabel"`

I want to convert to `AnyObject` by a given type from a string.

is it possible to do something like this?:

```
                                                 //This is a string
if let myConvertedItem = items["file"]!.item as? items["file"]!.type{
     //myConvertedItem is UILabel here..
}
```

is there's a better way to do this?

*edit:* I saw this function `_stdlib_getTypeName()` but swift doesn't recognize it. how can I make it declared? will it work also on `AnyObject`?

**The Solution I'm not looking for:**

do something like this:

```
if items["file"]!.item is UILabel{
     //ok it's UILabel
}

if items["file"]!.item is SomeOtherClassName{
    //ok it's some other class name
}
```

because this if list might be very long

thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a dynamic solution like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030814/swift-language-nsclassfromstring ?

Comment: Did you try to save in the dictionary an `AnyClass` object instead a simple string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it possible to do something like this?:

```
                                             //This is a string
if let myConvertedItem = items["file"]!.item as? items["file"]!.type{
     //myConvertedItem is UILabel here..
}
```

No. That is not possible.  Swift knows at **compile time** the types of all of its variables.  You can <kbd>option</kbd>-click on a variable and Swift will tell you what it is.  You cannot have a variable assuming a type at run time.

Look at this little example:

```
let random = arc4random_uniform(2)
let myItem = (random == 0) ? 3 : "hello"
```

You'd like `myItem` to be an `Int` if `random == 0` and a `String` if `random == 1`, but the Swift compiler makes `myItem` to be `NSObject` because it treats the `3` as an `NSNumber` and `"hello"` as an `NSString` so that it can determine the type of `myItem`.

---

Even if that worked, what would you do with it?  At the point of `//myConvertedItem is UILabel here..` Swift would know that `myConvertedItem` is a `UILabel`, but the code you write wouldn't know.  You'd have to do *something* to know that it was a `UILabel` before you could do `UILabel` things to it.

```
if items["file"]!.type == "UILabel" {
    // ah, now I know myConvertedItem is a UILabel
    myConvertedItem.text = "hello, world!"
}
```

It would be the same amount of code as the way you don't want to do it:

```
if myItem = items["file"]?.item as? UILabel {
    // I know myItem is a UILabel
    myItem.text = "hello, world!"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Is a `switch` expression a suitable solution for you?

```
if let item: AnyObject = items["file"]?.item {
  switch item {
  case let label as UILabel:
    // do something with UILabel
  case let someOtherClass as SomeOtherClassName:
   // do something with SomeOtherClass

  default:
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: it is a nice solution to go over switch case let as.. didn't know it is possible in switch.  +1 for that, but it's still the same problem, this list might be long, I want to do it generic that I can hold X types of classes

Comment: I suspect this is not possible. To send messages to an object in Swift you have to cast `AnyObject` to a specific type