# NSClassFromString works well in OC, but crashes in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

It works fine in OC:

```
NSString *controllerName = @"SecondViewController";
Class clazz = NSClassFromString(controllerName);
UIViewController *viewController = [[clazz alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

When I use swift:

```
let controllerName = "SecondViewController"
let controller:AnyClass = NSClassFromString(controllerName)!
let viewController = (controller as! UIViewController.Type).init()
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

It crashed at `let controller:AnyClass = NSClassFromString(controllerName)!`

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you don't force-unwrap?  Does `controller` get set to `nil`?

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030814/swift-language-nsclassfromstring/32265287#32265287

Comment: @K.Nimo Thanks for your commont!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift classes are namespaced now so instead of "SecondViewController" it'd be "AppName.SecondViewController"

```
    let nameSpace = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String
    let controllerName = "SecondViewController"
    let controller:AnyClass = NSClassFromString(nameSpace + "." + controllerName)!
    let viewController = (controller as! UIViewController.Type).init()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```