# Instantiating a nested class using NSClassFromString in swift

Tags: swift

I have a nested class defined like this:

```
@objc class A { 
    @objc class B{

    } 
}
```

and I need to instantiate `A.B` using `NSClassFromString`. I was able to do it for the simple class `A` but when I attach to the `NSClassFromString` parameter the `.B` string it just returns nil.

```
NSClassFromString("\(appName).A") // works... 
NSClassFromString("\(appName).A.B") //doesn't work.
```

I suppose that since nested class are not available in Objective-c the `NSClassFromString` just doesn't work for nested classes... in that case is there another way to initialize a nested class from a string?

// EDIT

is curious how the inverse function `NSStringFromClass`returns different format when executed for a standard class and a nested class:

```
"myApp.A" <---- STANDARD CLASS (A)
"_TtCC15myApp13A6B" <----- NESTED CLASS (A.B)
```

As you can see the format is completely different. What is that `_TtCC15`? Why the "." has been removed? I suppose that passing the class in that format to `NSClassFromString` should work.

Comment: Try marking class B as @objc like so: `@objc class B { }`.

Comment: Already tried... I update the answer though, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Try to prefix `class B` with `public` keyword. Like this `@objc public class B`

Comment: @NSDmitry sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: @MatterGoal what error does compiler tell you?

Comment: @NSDmitry no errors actually. It just returns `nil`.

Comment: @MatterGoal did you look at this responce? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32265287/308315 are you sure you're providing proper name for class?

Comment: @NSDmitry I suppose I'm doing it right since it works for standard classes but now for nested classes.

Comment: @NSDmitry I've added a couple of information to the question... the string format for nested classes seems to be completely different by the standard class format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that the following works in a playground (Xcode 8.2 / Swift 3):

```
// inheriting NSObject is required for `@objc`, at which point `@objc` is optional
class A: NSObject {
    class B: NSObject {
        override var description: String { return "foo" }
    }
}

let str = NSStringFromClass(A.B.self)
guard let anyClass = NSClassFromString(str)
    else { fatalError("no class") }
// cast to a type that defines `init()` so we can instantiate
guard let nsClass = anyClass as? NSObject.Type 
    else { fatalError("class isn't NSObject") }
// call `.init()`, not `nsClass()`; constructor syntax is for static types only
let instance = nsClass.init() 
print(instance) // -> "foo"
```

The oddball class "name" string is because the ObjC runtime doesn't understand nested classes (or other kinds of types that Swift can define but ObjC can't) -- within Swift itself, such mangled names are how types, functions and such get uniquely defined. (For example, name mangling is also how function overloading works: `func foo()` and `func foo(num: Int) -> Bool` have different mangled names internally.)

The bridging machinery can still be made to dynamically resolve a class given its properly mangled Swift name, but Swift name mangling is an implementation detail and subject to change. (At least until Swift 4 locks down the ABI.) So it's safe to pass the result of `NSStringFromClass` to `NSClassFromString` within the same program, but not safe to (e.g.) record a mangled name once in testing, ship that mangled name as a string literal or resource in your app, and expect it to work with `NSClassFromString` later.

Instead, if you want your nested class (or any other Swift-defined class) to have a reliably known name for use in the ObjC runtime, give it an `@objc(name)` (as described in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID55)):

```
@objc class A: NSObject {
    @objc(A_B) class B: NSObject { /*...*/ }
}
guard let anyClass = NSClassFromString("A_B")
    else { fatalError("no class") }
```

(Note this snippet won't run by itself -- the class `A.B` has to be referenced at least once somewhere in your process in order to be registered with the ObjC runtime. This could be as simple as putting `let t = A.B.self` somewhere in your app's startup code.)

Comment: Using ObjC name did the trick! About the rest of your answer, great explanation!