# Cant create class from string Swift

Tags: swift

Im trying to get class from string in Swift. It's not work. I try following:

print(NSClassFromString(dictionary[key]!) ?? "error")

It produce "error". However, in log i can see

```
po dictionary[key]!
"VacanciesCell"
```

Why is that happening?

Vacancies cell defined as:

```
import UIKit

class VacanciesCell: BaseCell, ModelBinding {

...

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? – Did you have a look at the various answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030814/swift-language-nsclassfromstring?

Comment: @MartinR because i want to get cell class to register it.

Comment: @Hamish i did edit my post, is there any other information you need?

Comment: May be you try to use Factory pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by following:

```
for (key, _) in dictionary {
    print(NSClassFromString(dictionary[key]!) ?? "error")
    print("key - \(key) val \(dictionary[key]!)")
    let cellClassStr = "AppName.\(dictionary[key]!)"

    self.register(NSClassFromString(cellClassStr), forCellReuseIdentifier: key)
}
```

Where "AppName" is app name.

Comment: I think you mean "module name", not "app name".

Comment: This sounds like a terrible way to register your classes. How are you storing the class names into the dictionary anyway? Why don't you just store the classes instead and call the `register...` method that receives a class?

Comment: @Sulthan i don't know difference, i add app name as string.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez because i want to dynamically register classes by passing dictionary to table view.